# bold fixed fonts in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I'm trying to use fixed width fonts in Java. I can use Courier or Lucida Console, but when I apply a "bold" style, it makes the characters larger in width and that's not acceptible in my application. Is there anyway I can force the bold characters to have the same width as non-bold characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Monospaced` should work on any platform.
On Windows, I like `Consolas`.
`Courier New` should also work.

Comment: "Monospaced" works. Courier New appears to be the same thing. Consolas doesn't seem to work on my machine (and I have Windows)

Comment: Not only that Monospaced works but it loads faster on my Windows machine.

Comment: `Courier New` doesn't work for me, the `|` character is a different width to the letters. `Monospaced` works fine though! +1

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to find a font face that renders with exactly the same width regardless of the bold property.  I am yet to find such font.

Answer (score 1):

re @Mario Ortegon's suggestion, I asked on a Sun forum and someone suggested Lucida Sans Typewriter, which does appear to work, but it looks pretty lousy. >:(

Comment: Guess we can't have it both ways :( (+1, this is a solution)